# Desktop.browse() fails with JDK 17

Tags: java, windows, exception, desktop

When I'm using `JDK 17` on `Windows`, the following simple code for opening a `URL` fails with an exception:

```
Desktop desktop = getDesktop();
desktop.browse(new URI("https://www.google.com"));
```

Stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to open https://www.google.com. Error message: CoInitializeEx() failed.
    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.ShellExecute(WDesktopPeer.java:115) ~[?:?]
    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.browse(WDesktopPeer.java:101) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Desktop.browse(Desktop.java:530) ~[?:?]
```

Any idea how to fix this? Is it a `JDK` bug? Most likely. I didn't find any related information about this online.

Comment: Did it work in previous JDKs? In that case, you may want to report it at [the bug tracker](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: @dan1st I think that site needs a developer account;  https://bugs.java.com might be a better place to report it.

Comment: Tested with JDK17 b33. Works fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have encountered https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8270269 issue, which is still in Open state.

Comment: Great, this sheds some light on the issue. I failed to reproduce it but he found out.